# ¿Cómo "individualizar" datos de un archivo de texto y agruparlos?

Tags: c#, file

Esta duda que tengo está dirigida al manejo de archivos en C#. Supungamos que disponemos de un archivo de texto (empresas.txt) con los siguientes datos:

```
EMPRESA EMPLEADOS   TIPO
MUNDO   123 SRL
GENERAL MOTORS  320 SA
AFA 300 SA
KNRETRA 50  SRL
CHEVROLET   540 SA
CGT 60  SA
```

Separados por un tabulador ('\t') cada dato (columna) y fila por un salto de linea ('\n').

Lo que necesito hacer es lograr agrupar datos de este archivo de texto para poder hacer comparaciones luego. Por ejemplo:

**1)** Contar que cantidad de empresas son de tipo SRL y SA.

**2)** Saber que tipo de empresa tiene mas empleado (si SA o SRL).

**3)** Mostrar el nombre de la empresa que tenga la mayor cantidad de empleados.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
string line;
        string path = @"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\SO\empresas.txt";

        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);

            line = sr.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                line = sr.ReadLine();

            }

            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excepcion: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fin lectura.");
        }
```

Sólo tengo la lectura del archivo. ¿Cómo puedo individualizar/separar los datos en strings y agruparlos por tipos? ¿Me conviene crear una nueva clase o todo dentro del main para mayor organización?.

Espero haber sido bastante claro. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola byte96. Por favor cuidado con este tipo de preguntas. Aunque compartistes algún código, en realidad no era mas que un esqueleto sin un intento real por resolver el problema por tu cuenta. Por hoy, parece que lograstes obtener una respuesta favorable. Pero no te mal acostumbres, porque no será siempre así. Consejo de amigo.

Comment: @sstan no podía/puedo avanzar de ningún modo no se ni por donde arrancar por suerte los chicos me han ayudado. desde ya, gracias por la sugerencia. un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener la información que deseas, considero que tu mejor aliado es Linq, donde al leer el archivo, asignarás su contenido a una lista de tipo `List<Empresa>`:

Definición de la clase:

```
public class Empresa
{
    public string EmpresaNombre { get; set; }
    public int Empleados { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Lectura del archivo y asignación de datos:

```
List<Empresa> datos = (from p in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\Empresas.txt").Skip(1) // Skip(1) solo es por si tienes un encabezado en tu archivo, tú sí lo tienes, por eso lo puse
               let parts = p.Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               where parts.Length == 3
               select new Empresa
               {
                   EmpresaNombre = parts[0].ToString(),
                   Empleados = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1].ToString()),
                   Tipo = parts[2].ToString(),
               }).ToList();
```

Ahora, toda la información de las empresas la tienes lista `datos`, con esto te será posible obtener todo lo que deseas.

1. Contar que cantidad de empresas son de tipo SRL y SA y

   ```
   var contarTipoEmpresa = from p in datos
                   group p by new { p.Tipo } into g
                   select new 
                   {
                       g.Key.Count(),
                       g.Tipo
                   };
   ```

El punto 2 y 3, pueden salir de la misma consulta:

2. Saber que tipo de empresa tiene mas empleado (si SA o SRL) y
3. Mostrar el nombre de la empresa que tenga la mayor cantidad de empleados.

   ```
   var contarEmpleadosEmpresa = from p in datos
                       group p by new { p.Tipo } into g
                       select new
                       {
                           TotalEmpleados = g.Sum(t => t.Empleados),
                           g.Key.Tipo
                       };
   ```

Comment: Hay un error en g.Key.Count(); no me permite contar. intente tambien como g.Key.Tipo.Count(); y no hay caso. Me darias una mano con eso ? Un saludo.

Comment: @byte96 edité mi respuesta, me tomé el tiempo para replicar tu escenario y creo que con eso sería suficiente ;)

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias le voy a echar un vistazo.

Answer (score 2):

Yo crearía una clase cliente para poder manejar luego los datos de manera más sencilla.

```
public class Cliente{
  public virtual string empresa { get; set; }
  public virtual string empleados { get; set; }
  public virtual string tipo { get; set; }
}
```

y cuando vas recorriendo el fichero, creas un cliente por cada línea y lo guardas en un listado de clientes.

```
string line;
List<Cliente> lista = new List<Cliente>();   //Creamos una lista para ir metiendo los clientes
string path = @"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\SO\empresas.txt";

try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);

    line = sr.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        Cliente aux = new Cliente(); //Creamos el cliente
        string[] laux = line.split("\t"); //Separamos line por los tabuladores, este método devuelve un array

        aux.empresa = laux[0];  //Rellenamos los datos del cliente
        aux.cliente = laux[1];
        aux.tipo = laux[2];

        lista.add(aux);  //Añadimos el cliente a la lista

    }

    sr.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Excepcion: " + e.Message);
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fin lectura.");
}
```

Ahora teniendo en una lista todos los clientes, es muy sencillo resolver lo que te preguntan, con recorrerla e ir mirando los campos ya lo tienes

Comment: ya comentarás si has podido hacerlo

Comment: Estoy en eso Pablo, muchas gracias me ha servido de mucho. Lo que si tuve que hacer algunos cambios.

El string[] laux = line.split("\t");  lo cambie por ('\t') comillas simples, y al compilar y mostrar la lista me aparece un error: **"Excepcion: Indice por fuera del limite de la matriz"**. Las operaciones de la Lista la tengo que hacer luego del finally no ? Osea como me ha quedado ordenada la lista ahora ? en terminos de string digamos que me ha quedado:
('MUNDO','123','SRL') cierto ?

Comment: bueno, si has podido hacer cambios y que te funcione es que has entendido como hacerlo, eso es bueno. Edita mi respuesta para arreglar lo que te haya fallado o comentalo y la edito para dejarla bien

Comment: Ahora tienes una lista de clientes donde cada cliente tiene unas propiedades que son empresa, empleados y tipo. La lista estará ordenada en el mismo orden que en el fichero. Si, en el finally no pongas las operaciones.

Comment: Pablo te hago una consulta: Al colocar luego del Finally
Console.WriteLine("Elemento" + lista[1]); recibo > Elemento ConsoleApp1.Cliente. El problema del indice fuera de los limites de la matriz todavia no lo he podido solucionar, creo que es por el split. Probe hacer ToString("\t"); pero tampoco he podido.

Comment: Lo que imprimes te imprime bien porque le pides un cliente, para imprimir su empresa por ejemplo tienes que hacer lista[1].empresa. Para el índice, asegúrate que se separan en el fichero por \t y lo que te queda en el array al hacer el split